# Load class in c# without creating object

Tags: c#

I am new to c# I have one question, In java we can execute static blocks of a class without creating any object  by using Class.forName("ClassName"), Like this can we execute static constructor in c# without creating actual object. I am providing the code in Java,pls Can any one achieve the same functionality in c#?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class MyClass
{  
    public static void main(String args[])throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
       Class.forName("Student");
    }
}

class Student
{
    static 
    {
        System.out.println("static");
    }

}
```

Comment: Same for C#, you can call static method just by calling it, example Console.WriteLine(...)

Comment: Arsen Mkrtchyan, I want to execute static constructor of a class without creating object of that class not static method.

Comment: If you execute any static method on that class, then this will cause the static constructor to be run, if it hasn't already.

Comment: Thanks to Peter Aylett.

Comment: Can anyone tell how to use accepted answer in the question mentioned above 'How can I run a static constructor?'